# Azure AD B2C Custom Policy sign in error: AADB2C: Encryption key must be a 256-bit key

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am using Custom policies according to the Starter pack (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/master/LocalAccounts)
and Custom Policy documentation. I am using custom policies in my web app.

I got an Azure side error after entering the right credentials on sign in page.

[image]

Comment: Can you include your custom policy as well as a screenshot of the keys you've configured as per this step: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom#add-signing-and-encryption-keys-to-your-b2c-tenant-for-use-by-custom-policies

Comment: And can you also explain how you had created the key in the first place? Are you importing your own key, or did you use the auto-create?

Comment: I paid attention to create signing and encryption keys by exacly following the link. After regeneration of the keys and IdentityExperienceFramework application the problem was solved. Thank you @Saca

Comment: Good to hear. Can you please upvote the answer and flag your question as answered?

Answer (score 2):

The error `AADB2C: Encryption key must be a 256-bit key` indicates an error with the key you configured. Please see the [add-signing-and-encryption-keys-to-your-b2c-tenant-for-use-by-custom-policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom#add-signing-and-encryption-keys-to-your-b2c-tenant-for-use-by-custom-policies) documentation for a step-by-step guide on how to do this correctly.

Otherwise, please post more details (policy xml, screenshots of key config, etc) so that we can provide you with more prescriptive guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error - the problem was that i forgot to switch to RSA as the Key Type.

...
4. For Key type, select RSA.
...

and take care to select the right key for Signature and Encryption.